# onUserInteraction() does not work in dialog preference

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I've implemented onUserInteraction() method in Activity preference and working like a charm. But when custom dialog box open, `onUserInteraction()` does not get fired. I have googled lots of sites, but couldn't figure out the proper way. Here is my simple snippet:

```
@Override
public void onUserInteraction() {
    super.onUserInteraction();
    resetTimer();
}
```